# ASP.NET MVC 4 Search Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitefinity

I'm stuck.  I'm trying to perform a simple search form and it will not return any results.

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult search(FormCollection frmCollection)
    {

        var search = frmCollection["searchString"];
        List<JobViewModel> lst = new List<JobViewModel>();

        var result = from a in db.jobs
                     join b in db.jobcategories on a.category_id equals b.id
                     join c in db.jobstatus on a.status_id equals c.id
                     select new
                     {
                         id = a.id,
                         title = a.title,
                         category_id = a.category_id,
                         category_name = b.name,
                         city = a.city,
                         state = a.state,
                         zip = a.zip,
                         status_id = a.status_id,
                         status_name = c.name,
                         description = a.description,
                         qualifications = a.qualifications,
                         required_education = a.required_education,
                         application_link = a.application_link


                     };
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            result = result.Where(s => s.title.Contains(search));
        }


        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var JobModel = new JobViewModel
            {
                id = item.id,
                title = item.title,
                category_id = item.category_id,
                category_name = item.category_name,
                city = item.city,
                state = item.state,
                zip = item.zip,
                status_id = item.status_id,
                status_name = item.status_name,
                description = item.description,
                qualifications = item.qualifications,
                required_education = item.required_education,
                application_link = item.application_link
            };
            lst.Add(JobModel);
        }

        return View("SearchResults", lst.AsQueryable());
    }
```

Here is my search form:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View All Positions", "ListAll")

@using (Html.BeginForm("search", "JobSearchController", "search"))
{
    <p>
        Search: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="search" />
    </p>
}
```

And here is my results page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Viaero.Next.Mvc.Models.JobViewModel>

RESULTS: @Model.Count()
POST: @Request["searchString"]

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var o in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span style="font-weight: bold"><a href="/about-viaero-wireless/careers/details/@o.id">@o.title</a></span><br /><br />
                        @(o.city + ", " + o.state)
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" target="_blank" href="@o.application_link">APPLY</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
else
{
    <p>Sorry, there are no results.  Please try again.</p>
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I put in the search box, I get zero results.  However, if I replace "where a.title.Contains(search)" with where a.title.Contains("Some String")"  It works every time.

I have verified that the text box value is getting passed to the view and that the controller can see it but it still doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you verify `var result = (from a in db.jobs where a.title.Contains(search) select a).ToList();` return any result?

Comment: @Win - This does not return any results.  I entered 'HVAC' into the search box.  However, if I use `var result = (from a in db.jobs where a.title.Contains("HVAC") select a).ToList();`, it WILL work.

Comment: Maybe reverse your search and try search.Contains(a.Title). This also has the upside of partial matching ie "HVAC service" should match "HVAC" or "service" or "HVAC service". However, I think your search string ins't being passed. Also, you should search against Jobs, then join the rest of the tables. Why join results data you aren't going to use?

Comment: @Steven Could you test with ***Trim()***? `var search = frmCollection["searchString"].Trim(); var result = (from a in db.jobs where a.title.Contains(search) select a).ToList();` If it still doesn't work, ***set a break point*** at `var search = ...` and see the value of ***search***. ***It might be that searchString value is null.***

Comment: @Win - I have tried with Trim() and it still does not work.  I can see the value that is entered into the search box being assigned to the search variable when I debug the application.

Comment: Interestingly enough - I can set the search variable manually: 
    search = "HVAC";

And it doesn't work either.  Only works if I directly enter it into the query.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the search variable is actually `null`, so you're not getting any matches. Try changing the incoming parameter to just be `searchString`. That should give you an idea if the form variables are mapping to the parameters.

```
public ActionResult search(string searchString)
```

Comment: I can debug and see the value that I enter into the search box being assigned to the search variable.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, adding the SQL wildcard characters did not work, however, the below DOES work.

```
var result = (from a in db.jobs select a).AsEnumerable();
result = result.Where(x => x.title.Contains(String.Format("{0}",search)));
```

Comment: I think this is happening because when you declare `search` by doing `var search = frmCollection["searchString"];`, you're creating an object, not a string. `String.Format` converts it to a string.